# How to change the dom volume with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend, jquery-selectors

Hey sorry if this question has been answered but im having trouble trying to adjust the dom volume with jQuery here is the code:

```
     <script>  
         $(document).ready(function() {
            slider = document.querySelector("input"); 
            
            slider.oninput = function() {
               progressBar = document.querySelector("progress");
               progressBar.value = slider.value;
               sliderValue = document.querySelector("span")
               sliderValue.innerHTML = Math.round(slider.value);
            }
         })
      </script>
```

I tried using a selector and then target the volume with [.volume](/questions/tagged/.volume) but it only adjusted the volume for the first audio tag not all of them.

```
       <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            slider = document.querySelector("input"); 
            
            slider.oninput = function() {
               progressBar = document.querySelector("progress");
               progressBar.value = slider.value;
               sliderValue = document.querySelector("span")
               sliderValue.innerHTML = Math.round(slider.value);
               let domConverter = Math.round(slider.value) / 100
               
               const volume = document.querySelector("audio").volume;

               document.querySelector("audio").volume = domConverter;

            }
         })
       </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First: You are targeting a single element. For multiple element listeners, use `querySelectorAll` and loop in a forEach (or other iterator)

Second: Rather than `element.oninput`, use `element.addEventListener('input',...`

Third, you were mixing jQuery and Vanilla which is fine, but I made it all vanilla for this example.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=range]").forEach(slider => {
    slider.addEventListener('input', e => {
      progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress");
      progressBar.value = e.target.value;
      sliderValue = document.querySelector("span")
      sliderValue.innerHTML = Math.round(e.target.value);
      let domConverter = Math.round(e.target.value) / 100
      const volume = document.querySelector("audio").volume;
      document.querySelector("audio").volume = domConverter;

    })
  })
})
```